# obj files empty with certain compiler flags

Tags: gcc

I am trying to create the dependency files for my c files.

```
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -MM -MT ./stuff/cat.c -MF ./deps/cat.c.d -fPIC -o ./obj/stuff/cat.o -c ./stuff/cat.c
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -MM -MT ./stuff/add.c -MF ./deps/add.c.d -fPIC -o ./obj/stuff/add.o -c ./stuff/add.c
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -MM -MT ./stuff/rot13.c -MF ./deps/rot13.c.d -fPIC -o ./obj/stuff/rot13.o -c ./stuff/rot13.c
[INFO] CMD: ld -r -o ./obj/stuff.o ./obj/stuff/cat.o ./obj/stuff/add.o ./obj/stuff/rot13.o
[INFO] CMD: gcc -shared -o ./target/libstuff.so ./obj/stuff.o
[INFO] CMD: ar -rc ./target/libstuff.a ./obj/stuff.o
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -o ./target/stuff ./obj/stuff.o ./tests/stuff.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccF2LsaB.o: in function `test_add_2':
stuff.c:(.text+0x2106): undefined reference to `add_2'
```

`objdump -d` gives me:

```
christopher$ objdump -d ./obj/stuff.o    

./obj/stuff.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

When compiling without dependencies, everything runs as expected!

```
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -fPIC -o ./obj/stuff/cat.o -c ./stuff/cat.c
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -fPIC -o ./obj/stuff/add.o -c ./stuff/add.c
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -fPIC -o ./obj/stuff/rot13.o -c ./stuff/rot13.c
[INFO] CMD: ld -r -o ./obj/stuff.o ./obj/stuff/cat.o ./obj/stuff/add.o ./obj/stuff/rot13.o
[INFO] CMD: gcc -shared -o ./target/libstuff.so ./obj/stuff.o
[INFO] CMD: ar -rc ./target/libstuff.a ./obj/stuff.o
[INFO] CMD: gcc -Wall -std=c11 -o ./target/stuff ./obj/stuff.o ./tests/stuff.c
[INFO] CMD: ./target/stuff
[INFO] DESCRIBE: ./tests/stuff.c => stuff
      [RUN!] It should... add 2 to input
      [..OK] Passed
      [RUN!] It should... add 2 to input with failure
      [FAIL] file: ./tests/stuff.c => line: 12
```

and ofc `objdump -d`

```
christopher$ objdump -d ./obj/stuff.o
                                                           
./obj/stuff.o:     file format elf64-x86-64                                                                            
                                                           
                                                           
Disassembly of section .text:                   
                                                                                                                       
0000000000000000 <cat_file>:                             
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64                
   4:   55                      push   %rbp           
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp         
   8:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Finally I found the reason is that `-M` and `-MM` would imply `-E`. See [the GNU doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options:%7E:text=Passing%20%2DM%20to%20the%20driver%20implies%20%2DE%2C%20and%20suppresses%20warnings%20with%20an%20implicit%20%2Dw.).

And option  `-E` will do nothing except preprocessing. That is the case.

If you want to generate dependency output file and comilpe source file at the same time, you can use `-MD` or `-MMD` instead. But they have some difference, see [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options:%7E:text=%2DMQ.-,%2DMD,-%2DMD%20is%20equivalent) for details.